How to write test for a js function with vitest mocking side effect function
I'm trying to write a test for a function in my Node.js/Express application using Vitest. The function generateData processes some request data, calls two other functions (getParsedData and getRefactoredData), and sends a JSON response. I want to mock these two side effect functions to isolate the unit test for generateData.
Here's the generateData function:
const generateData = catchAsync(
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const parsedData = await getParsedData(req.body);
    const refactoredData = getRefactoredData(parsedData);

    res.status(200).json(refactoredData);
  }
);

To test this function, I've written a test like the following:
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from "vitest";
import { createMocks } from "node-mocks-http";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import {
  generateData,
} from "../../src/handlers/resume.handler";
import * as resumeHandler from "../../src/handlers/resume.handler";

const mockRefactoredData = {//..//}
const mockParsedData = {//..//}
const mockRefactoredData = {//..//}

describe("generateData", () => {
  it("should respond with resume data", async () => {
    const mockNext = vi.fn();
    const { req, res } = createMocks<Request, Response>({
      method: "POST",
      body: mockRawData,
    });
    const spyGetParsedData = vi.spyOn(resumeHandler,"getParsedData").mockReturnValue(mockParsedData);

    const spyGetRefactoredData = vi.spyOn(resumeHandler,"getRefactoredData").mockReturnValue(mockRefactoredData);

    await resumeHandler.generateData(req, res, mockNext);

    expect(spyGetParsedData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockRawData);
    expect(spyGetRefactoredData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockParsedData);
    expect(res._getStatusCode()).toBe(200);
    expect(JSON.parse(res._getData())).toEqual(mockRefactoredData);

    spyGetParsedData.mockRestore();
    spyGetRefactoredData.mockRestore();
  });
});

However, I'm encountering an issue with the test. When I run it, I get the following error:
AssertionError: expected "getParsedData" to be called with arguments: [ Array(1) ]

Received: 

Number of calls: 0

 ❯ test/handlers/resume.handler.test.ts:108:30
    106|     await resumeHandler.generateData(req, res, mockNext);
    107| 
    108|     expect(spyGetParsedData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockRawData);
       |                              ^
    109|     expect(spyGetRefactoredData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockParsedData);

When I remove the spies and run the test below, it succeeds:
describe("generateData", () => {
  it("should respond with resume data", async () => {
    const mockNext = vi.fn();
    const { req, res } = createMocks<Request, Response>({
      method: "POST",
      body: mockRawData,
    });

    await resumeHandler.generateData(req, res, mockNext);

    expect(res._getStatusCode()).toBe(200);
    expect(JSON.parse(res._getData())).toEqual(mockRefactoredData);
  });
});


Don't unit test controllers. You're mocking things (Express request, response obejcts) you don't own.

moving the child function into a different module solved this issue

With node.js version 22.5.1 you can do the unit testing using the native node functions they have provided built in support for that below is one article you can refer to check and understand https://medium.com/@choudharynishantplawat/why-jest-is-so-last-year-embrace-node-jss-native-test-runner-v22-5-1-5ee177bf365e
